# Find Two largest numbers in a list without using Array

Tags: java

I'm Stuck with my homework. Basically,we need to Create a program to find the largest and smallest integers in a list entered by the user.And stops when the user enters 0. However we are not allowed to user arrays for this problem.

and one more condition : If the largest value appears more than once, that value should be listed as both the largest and second-largest value, as shown in the following sample run.

I have met the first condition of the program however I cannot meet the 2nd condition.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindTwoLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1, max1st = 0, max2nd = 0;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println("This program allows the user to create a list integers until the user enters 0");
        System.out.println("The program will print the Largest value and the Second largest value from the list!");
        while(num != 0) {
            System.out.print("Integer No." + count + " ");
            num = sc.nextInt();

            if(num >= max1st && num >= max2nd) {
                max1st = num;
            }
            if(num >= max2nd && num < max1st) {
                max2nd = num;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max1st);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + max2nd);

   }
}
```

I have tried to use this code.

```
 if(num >= max2nd && num <= max1st) {
max2nd = num;
            }
```

however when I run the program 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXHgJ.jpg - this shows.

It should print 75 and 45 . What can I do to meet the first condition and meet the second condition?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "first condition". Your code shows how to "remind" "maximum" numbers. What prevents you from adding more variables, like min1st, and min2nd; and to set them up in similar ways?

Comment: The first condition is to print the largest number and second largest number. I have done that part. However when the largest number appears twice . The largest number and the second largest number should be equal. That is what I dont get.The result should be like this : https://imgur.com/a/D2bkJIL However when I try running again but this time I did not repeat the largest number it prints this https://imgur.com/a/CmUHpxN . where it should be 35 and 26. I hope I am not confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you exceed your maximum number (`max1st`), your new maximum number will be set to `num`. But your second largest number will be the current maximum number. So try this condition:

```
if (num > max1st) {
    max2nd = max1st;
    max1st = num;
} else if (num > max2nd) {
    max2nd = num;
}
```

Comment: `max2nd`, not `max2st` :)

Comment: Thanks.It solved my problem in a very simple way. I am still confused as to how the program knows why the the greatest number has been repeated twice.

Comment: @JoshuaSalcedo - The program as it is currently written will find the two largest numbers, no matter what they are. If they happen to be the same number - ok, so be it. Or think about it in another way: as your program is running, at some point you will have two numbers as your `max1st` and `max2nd`. The first one will be the largest number ever, but the second one will be something smaller. Then comes along the other "largest number". Where will this code put it? That's right - in `max2nd`. After that no other number will be able to replace `max1st` or `max2nd` since they will all be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Please user If else in those cases. You have used two if statements that is replacing the value of max2nd.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class FindTwoLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1, max1st = 0, max2nd = 0;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println("This program allows the user to create a list integers until the user enters 0");
        System.out.println("The program will print the Largest value and the Second largest value from the list!");
        while(num != 0) {
            System.out.print("Integer No." + count + " ");
            num = sc.nextInt();

            if(num >= max1st && num >= max2nd) {
                max1st = num;
            }
            else if(num >= max2nd && num < max1st) {
                max2nd = num;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max1st);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + max2nd);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the conditions, please take a look

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindTwoLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1, max1st = 0, max2nd = 0;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println("This program allows the user to create a list integers until the user enters 0");
        System.out.println("The program will print the Largest value and the Second largest value from the list!");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        while(num != 0) {
            System.out.print("Integer No." + count + " ");

            if(num > max1st) {
                if(max1st > max2nd) {
                    max2nd = max1st;
                }
                max1st = num;
            } else {
                if(num > max2nd) {
                    max2nd = num;
                }
            }
            count++;
            num = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max1st);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + max2nd);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindTwoLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1, max1st = 0, max2nd = 0;
        do
        {
            num = sc.nextInt();
            max2nd = (num >= max1st) ? max1st : (num > max2nd) ? num : max2nd;
            max1st = num > max1st ? num : max1st;
        }
        while(num != 0)

        System.out.println("\nThe largest value is " + max1st);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + max2nd);

   }
}
```

If you need any more explanation I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach, this should solve your issue =>

```
import java.util.*;
public class BackedList {

    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1;
        List<Integer> integersList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println("This program allows the user to create a list integers until the user enters 0");
        System.out.println("The program will print the Largest value and the Second largest value from the list!");
        while(num != 0) {
            System.out.print("Integer No." + count + " ");
            num = sc.nextInt();

            integersList.add(num);
        }

        Collections.sort(integersList, Collections.reverseOrder());
        if(integersList.get(0) == integersList.get(1)){
            System.out.println("The number " + integersList.get(0) + " is first largest and " 
        + integersList.get(1) + " is the second largest number");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("The largest number is :" + integersList.get(0) + " and the smallest one is :"
        + integersList.get(integersList.size()-1));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection to get the largest and second largest like :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(5);
list.add(2);
Collections.sort(list);
int firstLargest = list.get(list.size()-1);
int secLargest = list.get(list.size()-2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindTwoLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 1, max1st = 0, max2nd = 0;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.println("This program allows the user to create a list integers until the user enters 0");
        System.out.println("The program will print the Largest value and the Second largest value from the list!");
        while(num != 0) {
            System.out.print("Integer No." + count + " ");
            num = sc.nextInt();

            if(num > max1st) {
                max2nd=max1st;
                max1st = num;
            }
           else if(num == max1st ) {
                max2nd = num;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max1st);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + max2nd);

   }
}
```

you are over complicating things with && in your if. if a number is greater than 1st 1sr gets changed if a number is same as first 2nd gets changed if its not bigger or same nothing happens.